# Subsetting pandas dataframe if column contains only ONE instance of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame, I only want to grab rows where the summary column only contains ONE instance of '->'. How can I do this in pandas?

**Input:**

```
idx  summary
0    McDonalds -> Wendys -> Popeyes
1    Popeyes -> Taco Bell
2    Carls Jr -> Arbys
3    Arbys -> Popeyes -> Taco Bell -> KFC
4    KFC -> Popeyes -> Boston Market
```

**Expected Output:**

```
idx  summary
1    Popeyes -> Taco Bell
2    Carls Jr -> Arbys
```

Comment: Given your previous question on how to generate this column. Why don't you act ahead and count the `notna`?

Answer (score 1):

`str.count('->')==1` will grab the `->` that occurs only once. Using the `loc` helps to identify which row it is located in, so the expected results will be the actual message, instead of `True` or `False`.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df["summary"].str.count('->')==1])
print(df_new)
```

Comment: Updated. Removed irrelevant lines to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is saved as variable df, this would produce that result:

```
ct_arrow = df.apply(lambda x: x.summary.count('->'), axis=1)
df = df.loc[ct_arrow==1]
print(df)
```

Comment: If you're using only 1 column value in row-wise apply, then you might as well apply it over that column only, i.e., `df.summary.apply(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following

`df[df["summary"].str.count('->')==1]`

Answer (score 0):

As @mozway suggested, use your previous dataframe as starting point:

```
>>> df
  first_stop  second_stop     third_stop
0  mcdonalds  burger king        popeyes
1  mcdonalds          N/A            N/A
2     wendys          kfc            N/A
3  taco bell          kfc         wendys
4    popeyes          kfc  panda express
```

```
>>> df[df.replace('N/A', pd.NA).count(axis=1).eq(2)]
  first_stop second_stop third_stop
2     wendys         kfc        N/A
```